# Raspberry Pi as Wiegand device - output Wiegand to receiver

Tags: raspbian, gpio, hardware, serial, wiring

I would like to build a Wiegand device from Raspberry Pi to output 37 bit Wiegand format data to Wiegand control unit receiver.

I don't want to read the Wiegand protocol on Raspberry Pi like from RFID card readers, but instead, I would like to act as something like this.

How can I do it? Is there any HW Wiegand interface for Raspberry Pi and library through which I can send Wiegand data?

I need that Raspberry Pi will output Wiegand 37 bit format data.

Anyone with experience with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wiegand is quite straightforward.  It is not a particularly onerous interface.

For an example of transmitting Wiegand codes see

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_tx_WD

```c
/*

This programs transmits Wiegand codes on a pair of GPIO.  It is
intended to be used to test Wiegand decoding software.

REQUIRES

Nothing

TO BUILD

gcc -Wall -pthread -o tx_WD tx_WD.c -lpigpiod_if2

TO RUN

sudo pigpiod # If the daemon is not already running

then

./tx_WD -gGPIO -wGPIO [options] {code}+

./tx_WD -? for options

E.g.

./tx_WD -g5 -w6 -s37 12345 67890 123 899999

NOTE

This code sets the used GPIO to be outputs.  If you intend to feed the
signals into a program under test it is probably best to use different
GPIO in the two programs and connect them by wires.

*/
```